# Xpath - looking for a specific element within div class

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy

With Scrapy I am scraping websites for interesting articles and can 'find' the required div class using:

```
response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "link")]').extract()
```

(see attachment) [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWylu.png)

However, I just want certain elements within the div class (link), for instance only the link (href), and the article title (clktrk). Using above xpath code, I get all the infos.

In addition, I would like to get the date of posting, which is the div class above (date pretyDate compact).

Comment: Ok - my apologies - first time user

Answer (score 0):

For the attributes use the at sign `response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "link")]/a/@href').get()`.

The date: `date_list = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "prettyDate")]//text()').getall()` then if you want you can use join: `date_str = ''.join(date_list)`